# iOS Use TabBar to change displayed view

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have a main TabBarController for my primary navigation. Under 1 tab, I have a controller that has another TabBar on the top. I would like to be able to switch between 2 views within the same controller if possible with this TabBar.

My idea is to have in my storyboard a ScrollView and a TableView on top of eachother and then use setHidden: on the 2 main views when an appropriate tab is selected (toggle 1 hidden and the other shown).

The problem though is that in the storyboard, I can never get them to play nicely. When I try to position 1 view, it is always becoming a child of the view that is behind it. For example, I have my ScrollView positioned well but then when I move the TableView into position, the TableView becomes a child of the ScrollView - thus if I hide the ScrollView I can never unhide the TableView.

Under the scenes table on the left of the storyboard, I can position the views to both be children of the main View (correct) without the ScrollView or TableView becoming a child of the other (correct). But, whenever I do this, the positioning I have done is lost and things are floating around all incorrectly.

Maybe I am going about this changing of views in a bad way or is there a way to get the storyboard to play nice?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the following:

- TabBarController A - Your primary navigation, lets say it has 3 tabs A1, A2, A3
- TabBarController B - Nested in a tab (e.g. A3) of the primary navigation, it has 2 tabs B1, B2
- B1 - A scrollView
- B2 - A tableView

To do this you don't need to set hidden, just use TabBarController B to present views in the same way TabBarController A does.

The screenshot below shows the storyboard layout:

NB - In order to link a TableViewController to a TabBarController in storyboards you control-drag from the TabBarController to the TableViewController and select 'Relationship segue - view controllers' from the pop up menu.

[image]